# How to run controller action instead of file in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I know how to configure the interpreter, xdebug and I too know that I we don't specify deployment point than PhpStorm will use its built-in webserver to execute the file in console or browser.

We can run any file just right click and select run (you should have configured the interpreter and deployment directory with web root url properly).

**My question is:** if we are working using Yii for example and in I'm `XYZ` controller file and I want to execute the `XYZAbc` action so how to configure this stuff? Because if I right click the `XYZ` controller file and run it so the `XYZIndex` (default route) will be executed.

Is there a way to run specific controller action in browser from PhpStorm?

Comment: Sure -- just create and use Run/Debug Configuration of the most appropriate type (e.g. Web Application) where you can specify exact URL to be executed. That's the only way ...  as there is no (known to me, at very least) plugin or built-in functionality that can *dynamically* convert current action/controller into a correct URL (as it's a framework specific + app specific) so that such configuration can be created from context menu (like you currently can do for "PHP Script" type of configuration or PHPUnit tests).

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html?search=configuration

Comment: I explored the IDE and there is not way to execute that. Hope JetBrains should embed an option to to run action from controllers in near future... Apart from it for time being we can create multiple run configurations to achieve the task to time being. Thats really booring...